# How to subtract date components?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

As today is `Friday`, which is `6` according to `NSCalendar`. I can get this by using the following

```
Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
```

How do I get weekday component of `Saturday` last week, which should be `7`?

If I do  `Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 6` . I am getting `0` which is  not valid component.

Comment: You want date of last Saturday?

Comment: No, I want component , which is 7, basically I like to know how to subtract components. For example Monday is 2. If I want to know component of day, 3 days before, it is Friday which should be 6. But if I do 2 - 3 , I get -1, which is invalid. Hope I am clear

Comment: You have to get the date then subtract the day from that, not just minus the component

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this, you have to get the date first then subtract again from it:

```
var dayComp = DateComponents(day: -6)
let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dayComp, to: Date())
Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date!)
```

Answer (score 8):

For that first you need to get that date using `calendar.date(byAdding:value:to:)` and then get day number from it.

```
extension Date {
    func getDateFor(days:Int) -> Date? {
         return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: Date())
    }
}
```

Now simply use thus function and get your days.

```
if let date = Date().getDateFor(days: -6) {
    print(Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use calendar and date components and put everything in a Date extension, something like:

(**Swift 4.1**)

```
extension Date {
    func removing(minutes: Int) -> Date? {
        let result =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -(minutes), to: self)
        return result
    }
}
```