# Having trouble trying to subtract a number from a date/time and setting that value in a textField

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I am working on an app that has a startTime, endTime and duration. The user can set the endTime by click a button and it sets the value to "now" in the format 12:02:03 PM.  I then want to be able to enter a duration time in minutes, let's say 20 minutes.

I have everything working where I can read the duration in real time as well as see the current time.  The issue is when I try to create a function to subtract the duration from the endTime. I cannot seem to get the syntax or the formatting correct.

I've done quite a bit of searching for examples of this. Here is what I came across so far.

[How to add minutes to current time in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465205/how-to-add-minutes-to-current-time-in-swift)

[How to subtract date components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394817/how-to-subtract-date-components)

[How to get the current time as datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-as-datetime)

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    let enteredValue = obj.object as! NSTextField
    timeString(time: enteredValue.doubleValue)
}

func timeString(time: TimeInterval) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let myString = formatter.string(from: Date())
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    yourDate!.addingTimeInterval(0-time)
    let wtf = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
    startTime.stringValue = wtf
}
```

The `controlTextDidChange` function is watching the `durationTextField` and I am able to print to console the input. I then want to be able to run the `timeString` function with the `durationTextField` value and subtract it from the `endTime` and then set that value to `startTime`.

One thing that is weird is Xcode tells me:

> Result of call to 'addingTimeInterval' is unused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking too many steps. Just create a `Date` that is `time` seconds from "now". Then convert that `Date` to a `String`.

```
func timeString(time: TimeInterval) {
    let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -time)
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    let wtf = formatter.string(from: startDate)
    startTime.stringValue = wtf
}
```

I'm assuming you want `startDate` to be `time` seconds *before* now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird, the warning tells you that [`addingTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval) creates and returns a new date.

Just **do** use the *Result of call to 'addingTimeInterval'*

The conversion `Date` to `String` and back to `Date` is pointless.

```
func timeString(time: TimeInterval) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    let newDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-time)
    let wtf = formatter.string(from:newDate)
    startTime.stringValue = wtf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of vadian and rmaddy I was able to make it work.

Here is my working code

```
func timeString(time: TimeInterval) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let endTimeValue = formatter.date(from: endTime.stringValue)
    let newTime = endTimeValue!.addingTimeInterval(-time * 60)
    let newtimeString = formatter.string(from:newTime)
    startTime.stringValue = newtimeString
}
```